# Grafana On Call multiple schedules

Tags: grafana, schedule, pagerduty, grafana-on-call

I'm trying to arrange an On Call schedule for my team, working in different timezones.

In PagerDuty I was able to schedule a person from Europe to be On Call for one week from 6am UTC until 6pm. From 6pm until 6am then a team member from Americas would take the On Call schedule for one week.

In this way every week every a member of the team would rotate to cover day lights from Europe and the other hours team members from Americas would cover.

In Grafana On Call I'm having an hard time to configure this, anyone who was able to do that?